# MongoDB, elasticsearch URL indexing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am new to Mongodb and ElasticSearch. My requirement would be to allow users to kind of bookmark either a full page or a part of the page.

I handled the front end but would like to know how to design the backend.. I.e. how to store the webpage details in the *mongodb* and index using elastic search. Would it be a good idea to store the whole web content in mongodb or just a url. In case its just a url, how does Elastic search find the keywords inside the url when we do a restful call.

Appreciate your time..

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is too little information to fully answer this. Are you sure you need both MongoDB and ElasticSearch? I wouldn't underestimate the overhead for development and operations.

In the upcoming release, MongoDB 2.4 will have (somewhat limited) fulltext-search capabilities.

ElasticSearch can do "regular" [GET queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/get.html) like a database. For searching inside a specific field (like the URL) see the [SEARCH documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/) and make good use of * (wildcard) and ~ (fuzzy search).

Comment: Hi,I would like to store a url as a document and when I do a search for a specific keyword,Elastic search would look at the contents of the url ,probably crawl and provide me the results if its matches the search keyword inside the web page.Would this be possible in elastic search ?

Comment: ElasticSearch can search one or multiple fields (depending on how you structure the content of a URL). Why do you need MongoDB at all (even though that's a point of discussion)?

Comment: I would store some of my user data in Mongodb.Elastic search would be used just for indexing some details pulled from the web.

Comment: Yeah, but why? Without any background or reasons, there's not much to be discussed...